# php subtracting a variable from a variable to get the value

Tags: php, variables, random, infinite-loop

Im learning PHP and I cant get this piece of code to work, I am just beginning to get into php and cant figure this out. The online validator reports no issues found but it sets of an infinite loop for me. Can some one tell me why the $eggUsage is not being subtracted from the $eggs.

Thank you :-)

```
<?php

    $eggs = 12;
    $eggUsage = 0;

    while($eggs - $eggUsage > 0) {
    $eggUsage = rand(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    $eggs = $eggs - $eggUsage;

    echo "You have {$eggs} left";
    }

    if ($eggs < 4) {
    $eggUsage = rand(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    $eggs == $eggs - $eggUsage;

    echo "You are almost out. BUY EGGS!";
    }

    echo "<p>Congratulations, you are out of eggs.</p>"  
?>
```

Comment: `$eggs = $eggs - $eggUsage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand()` expects 2 parameters, you have given 4 in your code.
Try `rand( 0, 4 )`.

Also, don't forget the `;` in your last echo, and you had a little mistake in the line `$eggs == $eggs - $eggsUsage`, which should be one `=`.

This code snippet works perfectly fine for me:

```
    $eggs = 12;
    $eggUsage = 0;

    while($eggs - $eggUsage > 0) {
       $eggUsage = rand(0,4);
       $eggs = $eggs - $eggUsage;

       echo "You have {$eggs} left";
    }

    if ($eggs < 4) {
       $eggUsage = rand(0,4);
       $eggs = $eggs - $eggUsage;

       echo "You are almost out. BUY EGGS!";
    }

    echo "<p>Congratulations, you are out of eggs.</p>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be `array_rand(0,1,2,3,4)` to pick values from the array, but as the array contains numbers from 0 to 4, `rand(0,4)` is ok.